# Get-Date Error in AD Password Expire reminder

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, office365

this is part of a code that reminds users if their active directory password is about to expire.

It used to work, but now I get this error out of a sudden! Maybe because the Local Machine Language is German with German Date Format, but I don't know hot to fix it! I would really appreciate the help.

The Code:

```
#Calculate expirering passwords and store them in an object
$today = (get-date).date

[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US';

$ExpirePasswordList =
foreach ($ADUser in $AllADUsers) {
    $PasswordLastSet          = $ADUser.PasswordLastSet
    $PasswordExpireDate       = (get-date $PasswordLastSet).AddDays($MaxPasswordAge)
    $DaysBeforePasswordchange = (New-TimeSpan -start $today -end $PasswordExpireDate).days
    
    if ($DaysBeforePasswordchange -le $WarningLevel) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Givenname                = $ADUser.GivenName
            Surname                  = $ADUser.Surname
            MailAddress              = $ADUser.mail
            DaysBeforePasswordchange = $DaysBeforePasswordchange
            PasswordExpireDate       = $PasswordExpireDate 
        }
    }
}
```

The Error:

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:6 char:43
+     $PasswordExpireDate       = (get-date $PasswordLastSet).AddDays($ ...
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

Comment: "Cannot convert null" This would suggest $PasswordLastSet has no value.

Comment: As it states: `Cannot convert null ...`, which probably means that password for the `$ADUser` account has never been set...

Comment: [1] I assume you created the `$AllADUsers` list with a `Get-ADUser` cmdlet. Did you also tell it to actually return that `PasswordLastSet` attribute in its `-Properties` parameter? [2] `PasswordLastSet` is already a DateTime object (local time) (or $null) so there is absolutely no reason to do `get-date $PasswordLastSet`..

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by **Theo** is correct **`$PasswordLastSet`** outcome is `null` beacuse you didn't mentioned `PasswordLastSet` attribute in its -`Properties` parameter of `Get-ADUser` and taking into variable `$AllADUsers`.

Try with below powershell code it should work for you.

```
$AllADUsers=get-aduser -filter * -properties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires | ft GivenName,Surname,mail,passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires

$ExpirePasswordList =
foreach ($ADUser in $AllADUsers) {
    $PasswordLastSet          = $ADUser.passwordlastset
    $PasswordExpireDate       = (get-date $PasswordLastSet).AddDays($MaxPasswordAge)
    $DaysBeforePasswordchange = (New-TimeSpan -start $today -end $PasswordExpireDate).days
    
    if ($DaysBeforePasswordchange -le $WarningLevel) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Givenname                = $ADUser.GivenName
            Surname                  = $ADUser.Surname
            MailAddress              = $ADUser.mail
            DaysBeforePasswordchange = $DaysBeforePasswordchange
            PasswordExpireDate       = $PasswordExpireDate 
        }
    }
}
```

***Reference : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32912.powershell-get-aduser-to-see-password-last-set-and-expiry-information-and-more.aspx***